# Trouble debugging a Mongoose find(): neither err nor success

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm a Mongoose newbie working on a collaborative Node project that I'm going late in the development cycle.

I have a model SourceContentType

```
    /**
 * sourceContentType model
 * @module
 */

var modelFactory = require('app/factories/model');
var nameMethods = require('./methods/name');

/**
 * This model will related contentTypes to sources and when documents are created for it,
 * they will imply that items for the given contentType
 * can be imported from the source (e.g. "photos" can be imported from "Facebook").
 * @class sourceContentType
 * @property {module:models/source~Source} source - source for this sourceContentType
 * @property {module:models/contentType~ContentType} contentType for this sourceContentType
 */
module.exports = modelFactory.new('SourceContentType', {
    source: { ref: 'Source',required: true },
    contentType: { ref: 'ContentType',required: true },
    itemsGetUrlTemplate:{ type:String, default: "https://${sourceHost}/${contentTypePluralCamelName}?access_token=${sourceToken}&limit=${sourceItemsLimit}&offset=${offset}"}

}, {
    jsonapi: {
        get: 'public',
        post: 'admin',

    }
}, nameMethods);
```

and am trying to search for a match on the source field from the instance methods of another model, Source, which is referenced in SourceContentType:

```
       /**
 * source model
 * @module
 */
...

 getSourceContentTypesForSource: function( done){
    SourceContentType.find({source:this.id}, function(err,sourceContentTypes){
        if (err) {
            debug("Error for Source.getSourceContentTypesForSource, ",err);
            return done(err);
        } else {
                debug("Success for Source.getSourceContentTypesForSource, ",sourceContentTypes,this._id);

            done(err,sourceContentTypes);
        }
    });

}
```

I'm trying to pass in the id of the Source instance, then get back all the SourceContentTypes that contain a reference to that source.  Although the method is called, neither of the debug statements above (error or success) prints out.

What is my major malfunction?  Any help much appreciated!

Comment: Are you calling `mongoose.connect` somewhere?

Comment: Yes -- this is a tiny part of a huge app that is doing many Mongoose calls before and after this bit…

Answer (score 0):

It was the `debug` statement.  `Console.log` traced the correct (successful) results just fine.  As I said, I'm a tiny cog in a big machine, and something was done to debug before my part in the program.